# How to turn off group by default ?

Tags: wpf, winforms, objectlistview

I use `ObjectListView` and put it on `xaml` file. When I click on the column header, it should sort data based on the column. I had added `olvServers.Sort(e.Column);` when the column click event emits. But it doesn't work.

```
<!-- declare bis -->
xmlns:bis="clr-namespace:BrightIdeasSoftware;assembly=ObjectListView"

// .... more codes

<!-- about ObjectListView -->
<WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="1" Margin="0, 3">
  <bis:ObjectListView x:Name="olvServers"
                      AllowColumnReorder="True"
                      ColumnClick="OnOlvServer_ColumnClick"
                      GridLines="True"
                      SelectColumnsOnRightClick="True"
                      SelectColumnsOnRightClickBehaviour="InlineMenu"
                      ShowCommandMenuOnRightClick="True"
                      ShowSortIndicators="True"
                      UseAlternatingBackColors="True"
                      View="Details" />
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

When I right click on the `ObjectListView`, and after `turn off groups`, it works. When clicking on the column header, the data will be sorted by ascending or descending order.

And my question is, how to `turn off groups` when initialing the `ObjectListView` object ? I had searched the `ObjectListView` assembly, and there is no such attribute. So, I don't know how to `turn off groups` when initialing. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: try to change the ShowGroups property of ObjectListView to false.

Comment: It works. Thank you. Could you post answer and I will accept it as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `ShowGroups` property of ObjectListView to false, this property is default to true.